# EF Core 7 error reading DB with null value to nullable type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm performing a query on a DB with EF Core 7, it's trying to read contents of a table into an object, and one of the properties is defined as nullable int. Table contains rows with this value being null.

`public int? Index { get; set; }`

Still EF Core throws the error below, seemingly surprised a nullable type is actually null ; ). Any suggestions what could be the problem here?

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'An error occurred while reading a database value for property 'ProductOrderProperty.Index'. 
The expected type was 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' but the actual value was null.'
```

**EDIT:**
Solved, see own answer below. Index was accidently marked as primary key.

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce this issue.  Where does the Exception happen?

Comment: Can you post callstack?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try to assign it directly like that?

```
public int? Index {get; set;} = null
```

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion, but see comment below. Rubber duck example..

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, been on it for hours and just now discovered the Index was accidentally marked as primary key (which it isn't of course) causing the problem. Fixed now.